# Excel: Exact match for search fuction

Tags: excel

I have a string of abbreviations (DIN, ISO, BS), that I want to search for within sentences. However, I only want to return it as a match if it matches exactly to my string.

EX:
Is this a DIN qualified part? 
**return DIN

EX2:
What's for dinner?
**return nothing

Comment: Does `DIN` = `din` if it is a full word?  in other words does case matter?

Answer (score 0):

use FIND:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&"DIN"&" "," "&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),".",""),"?","")&" ")),"DIN","")
```

If case does not matter just the full word change FIND to SEARCH.  Add more SUBSTITUTES to remove any other punctuation that may be in the sentance

[image]